# multiprocessing performances with different processes/core ratio

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

While learning about python's multiprocessing module, I've noticed that running a program using a number of processes that exceeds the actual number a physical CPUs result in a faster execution. Why?

This is my test code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import time

def my_func(to):
    out = 0
    for n in range(1, to):
        out += n ** n
    return out

def main():
    cpus = cpu_count()
    print 'CPU count: %i' % cpus

    run_args = [4000 * 12]
    for processes in [cpus, cpus * 2, cpus * 3, cpus * 4]:
        start = time.time()
        workers = Pool(processes=processes)
        results = workers.imap_unordered(my_func, run_args)
        for _ in results:
            pass
        elapsed = time.time()-start
        print 'procs: %i, time: %s secs' % (processes, elapsed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output, on my machine, is:

```
CPU count: 8
procs: 8, time: 6.22111010551 secs
procs: 16, time: 5.89230799675 secs
procs: 24, time: 5.81976008415 secs
procs: 32, time: 5.86776208878 secs
```

I've always thought that using a number of processes that exceeds the number of physical CPU will be not useful, but this shows I'm wrong. Anyone keen to explain? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU might be able to parrallelize some stuff. (CPU's for example can process 16+ bit per step at once.

I actually learned not to worry about too many threads. Some programs have thousand of threads and the CPU is pretty good at parrallelizing stuff nowadays.